# Search and replace - python with matching pattern

Tags: python

I have a file 'abc.txt' with following format.

```
+test1_app1 +o_test = /bin/su - user1  
+test1_app1 +ae_test1d = /bin/su - user2   
+test2_app +e_hd = /bin/su -  user1  
+crd_app +er_sd = /bin/su - user2  
+rod_app +eo_tsd = /bin/su - user1  
+rod_app +eo_tsd = /bin/su - user3
```

I like to search for specific users and then write to same file with different format

For user1 , it should change same file abc.txt with below. Please note I am reading the users list from passwd.

```
+test1_app1 +o_test = (user1) ALL  
+test1_app1 +ae_test1d = /bin/su - user2   
+test2_app +e_hd = (user1) ALL  
+crd_app +er_sd = /bin/su - user2  
+rod_app +eo_tsd = (user1) ALL  
+rod_app +eo_tsd = /bin/su - user3
```

passwd file contains all the users like user1,user2,user3 etc

This is what I have written so far:

```
import fileinput   
s=open('/etc/passwd','r')  
for i in s:  
    if 'user' in i:  
        for line in fileinput.input('/tmp/abc.txt', inplace = 1):  
            print line.replace(i.split(':')[0], "????")
```

I dont think I can achieve this trough line.replace. I may need to do this using re.sub? How to do that using re.sub?  I believe that you can group them together "\1" something?

Can someone please help?

Many thanks

Comment: You don't *think*?  Why don't you know?  The Python interpreter is the ultimate authority on this: run your code before you post it here.

Answer (score 0):

> I dont think I can achieve this trough line.replace. I may need to do this using re.sub?

You are wrong about this part. You can achieve it using `str.replace()` as:

```
 line = line.replace('/bin/su - user1', '(user1) ALL')
```

for changing the format for `user1`. In case you have multiple users in the form of `list`. Iterate over the list of users and perform this.

`re.sub()` would have been useful if you want to replace content based on some format for example `user<some_num>`. But for single user, `str.replace()` is the better choice

Comment: Thanks a lot . I may need to use re.search ( regex) for matching as whitespaces in  each line of file is not fixed. there might be more then one between /bin/su - user1 etc. I will try it out. Thanks a lot for answering this question